# Eclipse: тема меняется на стандартную после перезапуска

Tags: eclipse, themes

Для Eclipse установил плагин "Eclipse Color Theme". Выбираю любую тему - после перезапуска всегда встает тема по умолчанию.

Как сделать, чтобы оставалась выбранная тема?

Answer (score 1):

Советую присмотреться к плагину [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jeeeyuls-eclipse-themes). Его основные отличия от Eclipse Color Theme (они же - преимущества):

1. Позволяет настраивать любые элементы интерфейса, а не только окна редактора.
2. Все изменения применяются тут же, без перезагрузки IDE, без закрытия диалога настроек, и без нервирующих подтверждений.
3. Позволяет импортировать и тут же редактировать любые темы, доступные для Eclipse Color Theme.

Вылетов пока не замечено :)